# Htaccess rewrite rule php link not working Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've made some search about .htaccess Rewrite function, but I couldn't find any example with an  html reference.

I'm trying to redirect from my **example.com/products/category/** link to another page.
Here's the link what I'd like the .htaccess file to redirect:

```
    <a href="example.com/products/category/?category=bathroom">
```

I'd like to achieve this style:

```
    example.com/products/category/bathroom/
```

Here's my .htaccess ReWriteRule:

```
    RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /products/category.php/?category=$1    [L]    # Process category
```

Note that I'm using two different php pages for both. **page-category.php** and **category.php**

I've places it after

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
```

but still it doesn't work.. The only time something happened when I tried some combinations, it threw back an internal server error. Is there a problem with my RegEx or am I not doing the linking right ?

EDIT: I'm using wordpress, I forgot to mention that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Redirect 301`

`RedirectMatch 301 ^example.com/products/category/?category= /example/home/page-category.php`

Or you can use mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example/products/category/?category= /example/home/page-category.php [L,R=301]
```

same you can do for another file.

Answer (score 0):

as i understood from your question you need something like this in category directory .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*) category.php?category=$1 [QSA]
```

Now anything that is not a directory or a file inside category directory will be rewriten like /category/bathroom will be rewriten to (without redirection) /category.php?category=bathroom

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Wordpress. That's something I've should have told.